# Correct way of unrolling loop using gcc

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, loop-unrolling

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
            printf("%d",i);
    }
}
```

I want to do loop unrolling on this code using gcc
but even using the flag.

```
gcc -O2 -funroll-all-loops --save-temps unroll.c
```

the assembled code i am getting contain a loop of 10000 iteration

```
_main:
Leh_func_begin1:
        pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
pushq   %r14
pushq   %rbx
Ltmp2:
xorl    %ebx, %ebx
leaq    L_.str(%rip), %r14
.align  4, 0x90
LBB1_1:
xorb    %al, %al
movq    %r14, %rdi
movl    %ebx, %esi
callq   _printf
incl    %ebx
cmpl    $10000, %ebx
jne LBB1_1
popq    %rbx
popq    %r14
popq    %rbp
ret
Leh_func_end1:
```

Can somone plz tell me how to implement loop unrolling correctly in gcc

Comment: try doing `-O3` instead

Comment: I have tried using -O3 but still the same output

Comment: It's possible that the optimizer is finding that unrolling this loop is slower than just leaving it be.

Comment: *my* gcc unrolls everything just fine.

Comment: @n.m. Does it actually unroll all 10k iterations though? That makes code *super-fast*! :P (My gcc-4.8.1 only unrolls 8 iterations, sniff...)

Comment: @n.m what exactly are the flags you used

Comment: Same exact flags as yours.

Comment: @us2012 i am actually not getting any unrolling. Can you guys please tell me what flag you are using

Comment: Keep in mind that if the loop is unrolled too much, the loop code won't fit into the L1 cache, and a cache miss is a lot more expensive than a branch.  Unrolling all 10k iterations would probably be slower (relatively speaking) than not unrolling at all.  There's an optimal amount of unrolling somewhere in the middle.

Comment: It doesn't 'make code super-fast'. It makes it faster if the major overhead is the loop control stuff. In the case of printf() it certainly isn't: the I/O is the bottleneck. The compiler isn't obliged to unroll every loop.

Comment: @cdhowie: i understand that.. but my biggest problem is that i am not getting any unrolling as seen in the assembled code.

Comment: @NeelChoudhury You can't force the compiler to unroll.  At some point it has to make the call if unrolling will be worth it.  Try removing the `printf()` call and, say, increment some variable.

Comment: If you really care that much, why not use inline assembly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loop unrolling won't give you any benefit for this code, because the overhead of the function call to `printf()` itself dominates the work done at each iteration. The compiler may be aware of this, and since it is being asked to optimize the code, it may decide that unrolling increases the code size for no appreciable run-time performance gain, and decides the risk of incurring an instruction cache miss is too high to perform the unrolling.

The type of unrolling required to speed up this loop would require reducing the number of calls to `printf()` itself. I am unaware of any optimizing compiler that is capable of doing that.

As an example of unrolling the loop to reduce the number of `printf()` calls, consider this code:

```
void print_loop_unrolled (int n) {
    int i = -8;
    if (n % 8) {
        printf("%.*s", n % 8, "01234567");
        i += n % 8;
    }
    while ((i += 8) < n) {
        printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",i,i+1,i+2,i+3,i+4,i+5,i+6,i+7);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`gcc` has maximum loops unroll parameters.

You have to use `-O3 -funroll-loops` and play with parameters `max-unroll-times`, `max-unrolled-insns` and `max-average-unrolled-insns`.

Example:

```
-O3 -funroll-loops --param max-unroll-times=200
```

Comment: still i am not getting any unrolling.. i believe it gives a upper limit on the number of unrolling but it can not force a compiler to unroll

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 printf("%d",i);
```

with

```
 volatile int j = i;
```

and see if the loop gets unrolled.